# A bathroom floor turned super-slippery after 8 years

Tags: bathroom, flooring, tile

I have an 8 year old bathroom floor. It used to be just fine.

But for the last half year or so, it turned into a super-slippery floor. No matter how many times I clean it, with whatever cleaning agent.

What could have happened to it?

It is so slippery: you instantly lose your balance if you step in.

It is dry, and clean. I am beginning to think it is not a substance on top of it, but rather a lack of a substance?

Also note: if I examine the tiles carefully, I see repeated patterns, so it is not real stone, it is a fake print! (My builder was really cheap, and used low cost materials.)

Do tiles come from the factory treated with some anti-slip-coating that I have now lost, maybe?

What can I do?

Is it possible to coat it again with something that makes it less slippery?

[image]

**UPDATE**: I just noticed, it gets worse: the floor tiles are the exact same type as wall tiles. The builder just put wall tiles on the floor. Ugh.

Comment: Just FYI,if tiles like these were made of real stone,they would be ridiculously expensive,cold and a royal pain to work with. 99.9...% of any such tiles are stone-textured ceramic.

Comment: Have you cleaned a surface treatment off? Had to treat tiles with a micro-ball addition to a sealing coat once.

Comment: I suggest you google the string "What can I paint onto wall tiles so I can use them on the floor?" -- This is what your builder did.

Answer (score 2):

They make sealers that add friction to the surface. Search for something like "Anti Slip Penetrating Sealer". Just pick a product for your tile and follow application instructions.